# How to do a dark mode toggle button with VueJS and TailwindCSS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I want do a dark mode button that when I click the Icon change(like this
[image][image]
)

 But I don't find how to do this(only slide buttons). Btw I enable tailwind dark mode in tailwind.js with darkMode: 'class'. Soo what I should do for make this in Vue and Tailwind?